# Is this considered as a bad practice for regarding to scopes and variables?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

Let's say I have the following code:

```
var app = {};

app.post = {
    foo: function() {
        // defining a variable without the 'var' keyword inside a function.
        bar = "Hello!";
    }
}
```

I think the way that I defined the `bar` variable is not good. I know you shouldn't have **global** variables. but, I defined it inside of a method which is inside of an object.

Is it a bad practice?

Comment: Yes. In "strict" mode it would cause an error.  Without `var`, the variable is implicitly global.

Comment: Without the `var` prefix if you do `alert(bar);` outside of the foo function you'll see the code above has made it globally accessible.

Comment: You should use `var` keyword not only for the interpreter, but for the human eyes: at first sight, `bar` looks global.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's still a bad practice.

Without [strict mode](http://devdocs.io/javascript/functions_and_function_scope/strict_mode), this would cause `bar` to be implicitly declared global. With strict mode, this would cause an error.

Always use `var` to declare new variables, regardless of scope (and especially in inner scopes).

Comment: Thank you, I will accept your answer soon.